# Overflow Hidden having strange behaviour with transitioned elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

I was playing around with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravxqzpo/) when I came across a strange is

**note:** run snippet in full screen (isn't responsive yet)

```js
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box').toggleClass("init");
});
```

```css
html {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     height:100vh;
     background:#222;
     color: cornflowerblue;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     font-size:18px;
 }
 .box {
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     border-radius:50%;
     overflow:hidden;
     display:inline-block;
     transition:all 1.4s 1.4s;
 }
 .minibox {
     height:48%;
     width:48%;
     position:absolute;
     background:gray;
     transition:all 0.8s;
 }
 .box:hover .minibox {
     transform:rotate(45deg);
 }
 .mini1 {
     top:0;
     left:0;
 }
 .mini2 {
     top:0;
     right:0;
 }
 .mini3 {
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
 }
 .mini4 {
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
 }
 .circ {
     position:absolute;
     height:80%;
     width:80%;
     top:10%;
     left:10%;
     border-radius:50%;
     background:black;
     line-height:80px;
     text-align:center;
 }
 .box2 {
     top:38%;
     left:40%;
     transition:all 0.8s 2s;
 }
 .box3 {
     top:38%;
     left:60%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.2s;
 }
 .box5 {
     top:38%;
     left:20%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.8s;
 }
 .box4 {
     top:50%;
     left:30%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.6s;
 }
 .box6 {
     top:25%;
     left:50%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1s;
 }
 .box7 {
     top:25%;
     left:30%;
 }
 .init {
     top:0;
     left:0;
     transition:all 0.5s
 }
 .init:before {
     content:"Menu";
     text-align:center;
     line-height:80px;
     background:red;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:8;
     height:80%;
     width:80%;
     border-radius:50%;
     top:10%;
     left:10%;
     background:blue;
 }
 .box:hover .minibox {
     background:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">4</div>
</div>
<div class="box box2 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">7</div>
</div>
<div class="box box3 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">3</div>
</div>
<div class="box box4 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">5</div>
</div>
<div class="box box5 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">6</div>
</div>
<div class="box box6 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">2</div>
</div>
<div class="box box7 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">1</div>
</div>
```

---

The overflow which is set on the parent 'box' div isn't containing the 'minibox' divs - even though I have set overflow to hidden on the parent.

The Issue occurs with:

```
 .minibox {
     height:48%;
     width:48%;
     position:absolute;
     background:gray;
     transition:all 0.8s; <--this declaration
 }
```

Removing this line makes it 'work' (obviously without the nice transition I was looking for), Although I'm at a slight loss as to why.

On hover, the div elements appear 'square' for around a second before 'doing what it should do' - that is, for then circle.

[image]

When it should appear like:

[image]

With a transition.

Any idea as to how this overflow can be resolved?

Comment: Here is another related item - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693219/issue-while-using-css-transitions-opacity-change-overflow-hidden/31698580#31698580

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed with [null transform hack](http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/). More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955337/clip-child-to-parent-element-with-border-radius/28960887#28960887).

```js
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box').toggleClass("init");
});
```

```css
html {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     height:100vh;
     background:#222;
     color: cornflowerblue;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     font-size:18px;
 }
 .box {
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     border-radius:50%;
     overflow:hidden;
     display:inline-block;
     transition:all 1.4s 1.4s;
     transform:translateZ(0);
 }
 .minibox {
     height:48%;
     width:48%;
     position:absolute;
     background:gray;
     transition:all 0.8s;
 }
 .box:hover .minibox {
     transform:rotate(45deg);
 }
 .mini1 {
     top:0;
     left:0;
 }
 .mini2 {
     top:0;
     right:0;
 }
 .mini3 {
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
 }
 .mini4 {
     bottom:0;
     right:0;
 }
 .circ {
     position:absolute;
     height:80%;
     width:80%;
     top:10%;
     left:10%;
     border-radius:50%;
     background:black;
     line-height:80px;
     text-align:center;
 }
 .box2 {
     top:38%;
     left:40%;
     transition:all 0.8s 2s;
 }
 .box3 {
     top:38%;
     left:60%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.2s;
 }
 .box5 {
     top:38%;
     left:20%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.8s;
 }
 .box4 {
     top:50%;
     left:30%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1.6s;
 }
 .box6 {
     top:25%;
     left:50%;
     transition:all 0.8s 1s;
 }
 .box7 {
     top:25%;
     left:30%;
 }
 .init {
     top:0;
     left:0;
     transition:all 0.5s
 }
 .init:before {
     content:"Menu";
     text-align:center;
     line-height:80px;
     background:red;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:8;
     height:80%;
     width:80%;
     border-radius:50%;
     top:10%;
     left:10%;
     background:blue;
 }
 .box:hover .minibox {
     background:red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">4</div>
</div>
<div class="box box2 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">7</div>
</div>
<div class="box box3 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">3</div>
</div>
<div class="box box4 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">5</div>
</div>
<div class="box box5 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">6</div>
</div>
<div class="box box6 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">2</div>
</div>
<div class="box box7 init">
    <div class="minibox mini1"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini2"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini3"></div>
    <div class="minibox mini4"></div>
    <div class="circ">1</div>
</div>
```